# Empty image field with Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using Multer and sending data as multipart/form-data. I would like to save the new food object even if the image field is empty but when I send data with POSTMAN without an image req.files.image.name it sends me an error:

### TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
router.post('/food/add', function (req, res, next) {
    var food = new Food({
        name: req.body.name,
        image: req.files.image.name,
        category: req.body.category,
    });

    food.save(function(err, food){
        if (err){
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json({food: food, message: '¡Wohoo! Food added.'});
    });
});
```

How can I solve this error and save the object with an empty image field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an if statement.

```
var food = new Food({
    name: req.body.name,
    category: req.body.category,
});
if (typeof req.files.image !== "undefined") {
    food.image = req.files.image.name;
}
```

Or

```
var food = new Food({
    name: req.body.name,
    image: (typeof req.files.image !== "undefined") ? req.files.image.name : '',
    category: req.body.category,
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know how to pose a solution.